# Refactoring RJS/Prototype code into JQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I'm struggling to find suitable alternatives for methods in Prototype (converting to JQuery) and wondered if you guys could offer suitable replacements.

The RJS code I'm refactoring is:

```
 if request.post? && @success
    page << "window.location.href='/news'"
 else
    page.replace_html :user_overlay, :partial => 'login'
      if @error_msg.blank?
        page.visual_effect :appear, 'user_overlay', :duration => '0.7'
    else
        page.replace_html 'overlay_messages', @error_msg
        page.visual_effect :highlight, 'overlay_messages', :startcolor => "#404040", :endcolor => "#666666"
    end
```

It's loaded via a partial, and replaces elements in a div [login errors], we're running Ruby on Rails with JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend installing the plugin  [jRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails/tree/master).

I've been using it for a while now with RJS without any issues what so ever. Perfect drop in replacement for prototype.